# How to convert string to dictionary or some sort (from websocket client)

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

If a websocket client connects to a websocket server, it will send all these tags:

```
GET /x.css HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.12
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.2.12/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

This is one big string. Is there a way I can extract individual components from this? For example

```
print(data['GET'])
print(data['Host'])
```

that it prints the data that is requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read it line by line and split each line with the ': ' or the ' ' delimiter, then make a dictionary out of it.

```
text = '''GET /x.css HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.12
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.2.12/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'''

dic = {}
for line in text.splitlines():
    if ': ' in line:
        key, val = line.split(': ')
        dic[key] = val
    else:
        arr = line.split(' ')
        dic[arr[0]] = ' '.join(arr[1:])
```

or slightly more concise, you split by space and strip the ':' from the key name:

```
dic = {}
for line in text.splitlines():
    arr = line.split(' ')
    dic[arr[0].rstrip(':')] = ' '.join(arr[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you went into full detail on it! I'll accept as answer as soon as possible!